# Save array into json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to create a form from a JSON file which I can use to store settings in so that out of the box I can have something that looks database driven but is actually file driven which can then be used to setup the database and other settings. I am getting close but can't figure out how to submit the form and keep each row. As you can see from the JSON.txt I have a group of arrays and I want to save everything and be able to add new rows.

I know it would be easier to be database driven, but I am trying to make this idiotproof during setup, only problem is an idiot is setting it up :) Need someone with more experience to help me out.

JSON.txt:

```
[
    {"Setting_Index":"Server Name","Setting_Value":"server.com"},
    {"Setting_Index":"Username","Setting_Value":"name"}
]
```

Jquery Part:

```
     <script type="application/javascript">

   var indexValue = 0;
   function existingRow(S_ID, S_NAME){
        var existingRow ='<tr><td>Setting Name</td><td><input type="text" id="Setting_Index" value="'+S_ID+'"></td><TD>Value</td><td><input type="text" id="Setting_Value" value="'+S_NAME+'"></td></tr>';
        $("#applyTable").append(existingRow);
        }
   function addRow(S_ID, S_NAME){
        var addRow ='<tr><td>Setting Name</td><td><input type="text" id="Setting_Index" value=""></td><TD>Value</td><td><input type="text" id="Setting_Value" value=""></td></tr>';
        $("#applyTable").append(addRow);
        }

function populateRow(foo){
    $(foo).each(function(i, v){
    existingRow(v.Setting_Index, v.Setting_Value);
    });
}
//Get json data from file to be used in functions above
$.get( "./json/load.json", function( data ) {
populateRow( data );
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table width=400>
<tr><th>Setting</th><th>Value</th></tr>
</table>

<form action="" method="POST" id="saveSettings">
<table class="myTable" border="1px" style="width:400px;"  >
<tbody id="applyTable"> 
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" name="Setting_Index" value="test">
<input type="text" name="Setting_Value" value="test">
<input type="submit" name="Update" id="update"/>
<input type="button" value="Add" border="1px" onclick="addRow()" />
</form>
```

Functions.php (was trying to use it in the form action, have gone in a few circles)

```
$data = $_POST;
// $data is the posted data
// do what you want with it
$post_data = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$json_data = "[";
$json_data .= $post_data;
$json_data .= "]";
file_put_contents("./json/save.json.test", $json_data);
echo $json_data;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of wrapping your json in `"["` and `"]"`?

Comment: Using the brackets allowed me to have each line in the JSON file be a separate array so I could have a bunch of items with the same ID but different values. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yes, an array of objects, such as your JSON.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.getJSON()`. This way `data` is a JS object and not a string. I also recommend to just use a for loop instead of jQuery's `each()`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, use `json_decode()` to parse the json.txt file into a PHP array. Then, append your new `$POST[]` variables onto that array. Finally, `json_encode()` the full array and re-write the file.

Also, make sure you do some validation on the `$_POST` data, otherwise you might get some data you'd never expect a user to type.

I would not recommend building a JSON object/array by hand.